# Basic properties of inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$P$ is the set of the positive numbers and $<$ is defined in terms of $P$.

The basic properties of inequalities are $P10-P12$:

1. $P10$ (Trichotomy) For any numbers $a$, verified one and only one of the following afirmacions:
   1.1. (i) $a=0$,

   1.2. (ii) $a$ belongs to $P$,

   1.3. (iii) $-a$ belongs to $P$.
2. $P11$ ($P$ is closed under addition) If $a$ and $b$ belongs to $P$, then $a+b$ belongs to $P$.
3. $P12$ ($P$ is closed under product) If $a$ and $b$ belongs to $P$, then $a\cdot b$ belongs to $P$.

Suppose that $P10-P12$ are replaced by:

1. $(P'10)$ For any number $a$ and $b$ are verified one, and only one, of the following relations:

   1.1. $(1)$ $a=b$

   1.2. $(2)$ $a<b$

   1.3. $(3)$ $b<a$
2. $(P'11)$ For any $a$, $b$ and $c$, if $a<b$ and $b<c$, then $a<c$.
3. $(P'12)$ For any $a$, $b$ and $c$, if $a<b$, then $a+c<b+c$.
4. $(P'13)$ For any $a$, $b$ and $c$, if $a<b$ and $0<c$, then $ac<bc$.

How can I prove that $P10-P12$ can be deduced as theorems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two successive applications of $P'12$ do see that if $a<b$ and $c<d$, then $a + c <b + c <b + d$, so that $a + c <b + d$, $P'11$. In particular, if $0 <b$ and $0 <d$, then $0 <b + d$, which shows $P11$. It follows from there, moreover, that if $a <0$, then $-a> 0$; because if $-a <0$ is fulfilled, then $0 = a + (- a) <0$, contradicting $P'10$. Consequently, any number $a$ exactly satisfies one of the conditions $a = 0$, $a> 0$, $a <0$, the last of which is equivalent to $-a> 0$. This shows $P10$. Finally, $P'13$ do see that if $0 <a$ and $0 <c$, then $0 <ac$, which shows $P12$.